# How to use Enum from another Class in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, enums

What is the proper way to use my Enum values from a different class?

```
Public Class MainClass
    Private Sub asd()
        ' does not work:
        AnotherClass.WriteSomething(VAL_LIST.VAL_1, DateTime.Now.ToString)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class AnotherClass
    Enum VAL_LIST
        VAL_1
        VAL_2
        VAL_3
    End Enum

    Public Sub WriteSomething(ByVal myVal As VAL_LIST, ByVal myString As String)
        Dim _string As String = "Today is " & myString
    End Sub
End Class
```

It says << 'VAL_LIST' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. >>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a default scope of objects in a class which is independent of the scope of the class itself.

By default `Structures` and `Enums` are `Private` and Variables are `Public`.

Best practise is to specify the `Public`/`Private` scope explicitly so you can do something like this:

```
Public Class AnotherClass
    Public Enum VAL_LIST
        VAL_1
        VAL_2
        VAL_3
    End Enum
End Class
```

You have to now reference the Enum via the class Name:

```
AnotherClass.VAL_LIST.VAL_1
```

Although in your example `WriteSomething` is an instance member so you need to do the following:

```
Dim ac As New AnotherClass 
ac.WriteSomething(AnotherClass.VAL_LIST.VAL_1, DateTime.Now.ToString)
```

Also please rename your Enum to something more meaningful and don't use underscores to follow best practise.

Full working example:

```
Public Class MainClass
    Private Sub Foo()
        Dim ac As New AnotherClass
        ac.WriteSomething(AnotherClass.ValueList.Value1, DateTime.Now.ToString)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class AnotherClass
    Public Enum ValueList
        Value1
        Value2
        Value3
    End Enum

    Public Sub WriteSomething(ByVal myVal As ValueList, ByVal myString As String)
        Dim _string As String = "Today is " & myString
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't worked for me. I've tried it before posting.

Comment: I've tried it too. It gives me the error: "reference to a non shared member requires an object reference"

Comment: That is because WriteSometing is an instance member, so you either need an instance of `AnotherClass`, or make the `WriteSomething` method `Shared` e.g. `Public Shared Sub WriteSomething(ByVal myVal As VAL_LIST, ByVal myString As String)`

Comment: WriteSomething calls another methods. Should I make them shared too? Because I tried to do that and gave me some error.

Comment: Shared methods can only call Shared methods, sounds like you need an instance of AnotherClass instead e.g. `Dim ac As New AnotherClass
        ac.WriteSomething(AnotherClass.VAL_LIST.VAL_1, DateTime.Now.ToString)` and then remove the `Shared`

Comment: I have now posted a fully working example based on your original code

Comment: Be sure that a) the Enum has been declared public, b) WriteSomething is NOT declared Shared, c) you are calling WriteSomething from an instance of AnotherClass (ac.WriteSomething, not AnotherClass.WriteSomething), and d) none of the methods called by the implementation of WriteSomething are Shared and then call a non-Shared method.

Answer (score 4):

You need to provide an access modifier for your enum.  Be default (if left off), it's private.

```
Public Class AnotherClass
    'NOTE enum now has an access modifier.
    Public Enum VAL_LIST
        VAL_1
        VAL_2
        VAL_3
    End Enum

    '...
End Class
```

**NOTE:** you should **always** use access modifiers to avoid confusion and reduce errors.

**ADDITIONAL NOTE:** Though superfluous to this topic, I would also suggest you read up on proper naming conventions, specifically -- in your case -- [with regard to enums](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x252001%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).  You should name your enums and their values using [Pascal Case](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), e.g. `ValList`.  Furthermore, I would choose more descriptive names.  `VAL_LIST` doesn't really indicate what it's for, and certainly `VAL_1` etc. don't indicate what they are for either.

Comment: Your solution doesn't worked for me. I've tried it before posting.

Comment: I agree that you should explicitly state access modifiers. Eliminates confusion.

Comment: @mafap did you specify the class name first? Going off roryap's example, you'd need to write the following to use the Enum:

`AnotherClass.VAL_LIST.VAL_1`

Comment: Yes @Sylverac, I've tried it too. It gives me the error: "reference to a non shared member requires an object reference"

Comment: @mafap -- no, you shouldn't be getting that error.  There's something you're not telling us.

Comment: I know @roryap, my script is a "bit" longer. I just tried to reproduce the error.